# Android kotlin firebase data posted on firebase is always null I am not sure what I am doing wrong here below are the code snippet and screenshots

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

This is where I am trying to save it to the Firebase Firestore in log I can see it is posted but on the Firebase console, it always shows null.

[image]

**These are the data class**

```
data class Users(
val name: String?="",
val email:String?="",
val phone: String?="",
val avatar: String?=null,
val user_id:String?=""
```

)

```
data class UserLocation(
var geo_location: GeoPoint? = null,
@ServerTimestamp
var timestamp: Date? = null,
var users: Users? = null
```

)

**BUT IN FIRESTORE IT IS ALWAYS POSTED AS NULL**

[image]

**This is the user location const value **

```
 const val USER_LOCATION = "user locations"
```

**These are the places from where userlocation are been updated**

```
 private fun getDeviceLocation() {
    if (checkPermissions()) {
        if (isLocationEnabled()) {
            fusedLocationProviderClient.lastLocation.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
                val location = task.result
                if (location == null) {
                    requestNewLocationData()

                } else {
                    val geoPoint = GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.latitude)

                    Log.d(TAG, "UserLocation" + geoPoint.latitude)
                    Log.d(TAG, "UserLocation" + geoPoint.longitude)

                    userslocation.geo_location = geoPoint
                    userslocation.timestamp = null

                    saveUserLocation()

                }
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Turn on location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            val intent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

This is to get the user details

```
   private fun getUserDetails() {
    firestoreDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val userrefd = firestoreDatabase.collection(USER_DETAILS)
        .document(auth.uid.toString())
    userrefd.get().addOnSuccessListener {
        val user = it.toObject(Users::class.java)
        Log.i("firebaseImp", "Got value ${it.data}" + user)
        userslocation.users = user


    }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("firebaseImp", "Error getting data", it)
        }
}
```

Comment: Please show us how is `USER_LOCATION` defined.

Comment: Hi, Alex I have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

To be able to read the correct User data in Firestore, you have to use the correct operations. So you'll need to change:

```
//                             
private fun getUserDetails(userLocation: UserLocation) {
    firestoreDatabase = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
    val userrefd = firestoreDatabase.collection(USER_DETAILS)
        .document(auth.uid.toString())
    userrefd.get().addOnSuccessListener {
        val user = it.toObject(Users::class.java)
        Log.i("firebaseImp", "Got value ${it.data}" + user)
        userslocation.users = user

        //val locationRef = ... //
        locationRef.set(userLocation).addOnCompleteListener(/*.../*); //

    }
        .addOnFailureListener {
            Log.e("firebaseImp", "Error getting data", it)
        }
}
```

And when you call the above method call it by passing the `userLocation` object as an argument:

```
getUserDetails(userLocation)
```

To always be sure that you're using the exact same object.

Comment: Sorry if I have misunderstood but I am trying to post the user data to user location in firebase and it always getting posted as null

Comment: I have try to use the method I can see the users data is been fetched either ways and on saveuserdetails  on complete listener it shows the data in the log but on firebase its still posted as null

Comment: Have you tried to use the solution in my answer, where I mentioned passing the `userLocation` object into the function?

Comment: Yes i did and i am calling the function from onCreateView in fragment

Comment: So have you tried to use the solution in my answer? What is the result?

Comment: well I am still not able to post the user data in user locations. I am just curious if on success it shows the data in log why still its posted as null in firebase firestore

Comment: Most likely because that object by the time you're writing the data is null.

Comment: No i am sorry it did not helped i am getting the data in result.data but when i map it to object it gives null value

Comment: It means that most likely it is still null. You have to check that before using it.

Comment: i am getting logs on oncomplete if issuccessful listener where geo location is been posted but not the user data

Comment: No user data, because it is null. Be sure to have the right order for your operations.

Comment: Is there everything alright?

Comment: Yes I got it as I have two types of auth google and email and I am setting the user data from both methods and they seems to be getting called simultaneously. The second method is called over the first method and that is making the data null but thanx for your help and support

Comment: I mean the firebase team can implement such thing when one auth type already have the data inserted to the database then give some waring or just ignore it

Comment: Can I help with other info?

Comment: No that would be all thank you